# How many views/controllers (JavaFX MVC pattern)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, fxml

I'm new at MVC pattern in JavaFX applications. I'm studying and trying to apply this pattern to my JavaFX app. But on all my searches, I couldn't found an answer on what follows.

In my app, I have a `BorderPane` object containing a `TableView` object, an `ImageView` object, some `Button` instances and other controls like `TextField` objects, etc.

Now, I don't have already the code for controllers, model, and the FXML files for the views, but just some drafts, because my question is:
**assuming that I want to have a controller for each different view,** how many controllers and views I should create to handle the data shown in the BorderPane object? I mean, what is the granularity, the level of detail I should use for my controllers and my views? The alternative I thought of are:

1. one view (FXML file) for a `TableView` object and a controller associated to that view, one view (FXML file) for `Button` objects and a controller associated to it, and one view (FXML file) for the `ImageView` object and a controller associated to it;
2. less detail, that is one view for `TableView` and `ImageView` object and a single controller for it, and one view for the buttons with an associated controller;
3. even less detail, that is a single FXML file for the `BorderPane` object and all the UI elements that it contains and a single controller which controls all the events and bindings with the model.

At the start, I expected to have the third option, but I saw in some examples that there is a controller and a view for a single UI element, and not for the root UI element that contains all the JavaFX controls.

P.S.: English is not my first language, I hope I explained it well.

Answer (score -1):

JavaFX already follows MVC design pattern, and you have the option to create a controller for every javafx design file (.fxml). I would recommend creating a controller for every ".fxml" file. [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) provides an organized way of doing this where you can create your design file and specify "Controller class".

[image]